# UINavigationController and back button action

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have an two `controllers` 1st is `self` and 2nd is `maincontroller`, where I'm pushing `maincontroller` in **stack**, so the back button is automatically coming.

Here I need to make an alert when the user presses the back button.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Or you can use the `UINavigationController`'s delegate methods. The method [`willShowViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UINavigationControllerDelegate/navigationController%3awillShowViewController%3aanimated%3a) is called when the back button of your VC is pressed.

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

Comment: Also what I wanted. :-) For the record, you need to implement the protocol on the view controller you navigate back to.

Comment: This solutions works great and is the most efficient. Be sure that the connection to your navigationController delegate is in -(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated, otherwise alert also appears when the first viewcontroller launches the first time.

Comment: @Morkrom Yes it is called every time a view controller is shown in the navigation controller, its better if you check the view controller parameter to make necessary changes.

Comment: And use 

    if([viewController isKindOfClass:[CustomViewController class]]){
        ..code..
    }

To specify on what viewcontroller it should show a messsage

Comment: This method will be called whenever the View will disappear, not only when the back button is pressed.  For example, if you push another view (a modal one for example), this method is called too.

Comment: @SébastienStormacq you'd just check the view controller passed to the delegate method against the self.presentingViewController property then, to make sure the change was triggered by the back button (most likely).

Answer (score 8):

First hide the back button by using

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

and then create your own Custom Button:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backBtn =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(popAlertAction:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=backBtn;
[backBtn release];
```

and your selector is here:

```
- (void)popAlertAction:(UIBarButtonItem*)sender
{
    //Do ur stuff for pop up
}
```

Comment: K guys thanks, that's the second option, is there any way to detect the back button action of UINavigationController..?

Comment: What about `b`? Fix it please.

Comment: @HarishSaran What do you mean? Do you need to go back when you click on the alert view?

Comment: Great suggestion, this worked for me as I'm doing a custom navigation controller and couldn't implement the delegate callbacks as the correct answer.

However, I could *not* set `hidesBackButton = YES` as this would cause some visual artifacts when manually pushing new `UINavigationItem`'s manually.

Comment: Note, you need to to put "self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES" on the parent viewcontroller before you present the viewcontroller with the custom back button.

Answer (score 7):

**Best and Easiest way**

Try putting this into the view controller where you want to detect the press:

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    if ([self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self]==NSNotFound) {
       // back button was pressed.  We know this is true because self is no longer
       // in the navigation stack.  
    }
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create your own [`UIBarButtonItem`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and set it as the `leftBarButtonItem` in `viewDidLoad` method of `mainController`.

For example (here I used a system item but you can also create a different one, see class reference for details).

```
UIBarButtonItem *leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(showAlertView:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButtonItem;

// only if you don't use ARC
// [leftBarButtonItem release];
```

where

```
- (void)showAlertView:(id)sender
{
    // alert view here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add a custom back button with an action and set your alert in that action method.You can add your custom back button from here:  http://www.applausible.com/blog/?p=401

Answer (score 0):

**viewControllerCount** - is the var that holds the number of viewControllers previously was in the UINavigationController. Then, we check if **viewControllerCount > [viewControllers count]** if so, we know that we will get back (i.e. Back button imitation).

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
      willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                    animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSArray *viewControllers = [navigationController viewControllers];

    if (viewControllerCount > [viewControllers count])
    {
        // your code
    }

    viewControllerCount = [viewControllers count];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
extension ViewController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {
// when the self != viewcontroller ,it's mean back
     func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
          if self != viewController { 
             // your code
           }
}}
```

Answer (score -1):

create a button and give the button action as follows.

```
[self alert];
```

and when the alert is displayed, after tapping over yes

```
[self.navigationController popViewController];
```

after this,

```
self.navigationController.LeftBarButton = myButton;
```

this may help

Comment: What is the alert for?

Comment: @richy thanks for commenting on an answer this old. The alert is for showing the alert as asked in the question.