# set navigation backBarButtonItem to go to specific UIViewController in Swift

Tags: swift, action, backbarbuttonitem

I need the navigation's back button always pops a specific UIViewController.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //set title image
    var logoImage:UIImage = UIImage(named: "barra")!
    var logoImageView : UIImageView = UIImageView(image: logoImage)
    logoImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)
    logoImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    logoImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center
    logoImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    self.navigationItem.titleView = logoImageView

    //set back image
    var backImage:UIImage = UIImage(named: "freccia")!
    backImage = backImage.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title:"", style: .Plain,target: self, action: "goToServizi:")
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = backImage
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = backImage

    //set menu image
    var menuImage:UIImage = UIImage(named: "menu")!
    menuImage = menuImage.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.image = menuImage

}

func goToServizi(sender: UIBarButtonItem)
{
    self.navigationController?.popToViewController(ServiziVC(), animated: true)// here I add a breakpoint, but it is never executed.
}
```

`ServiziVC` is the UIViewController that I need to show every time I click on the Back button.

I can't understand why `goToServizi` func is not called. Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the example for you.

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Customise your barButton Like this
    var backImage:UIImage = UIImage(named: "freccia")!
    backImage = backImage.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
    var backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: backImage, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered, target: self, action: "goToThird")
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
}

func goToThird(){

    //Initiate newViewController this way
    let ThirdView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ThirdViewController") as ThirdViewController

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ThirdView, animated: true)
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Click on the ViewController which you want to initiate with identifier and you can find StoryBoard ID in Identity Inspector like shown in below Image.

[image]

[HERE](https://github.com/DharmeshKheni/Customized-bar-button) is the example for you for more reference.

Modify code as per your need.may be this will help you.

Comment: where do I have to add identifier for the viewcontroller? In this way how can I add image for the back button?

Comment: I tried out your code, it worked. But I have another question, I have about 20 viewcontrollers with custom back button, so I have to change the codes    to yours. How can I push the right view?

Comment: You have to tell every button what it will initiate.

Answer (score 0):

self.navigationController?.popToViewController(ServiziVC(), animated: true)You can't customize the back button action like that. This works:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true;
    var backImage:UIImage = UIImage(named: "freccia")!
    backImage = backImage.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
    var fakeBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: backImage, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered, target: self, action: "goToServizi:")
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = fakeBackButton;
}

func goToServizi(sender: UIBarButtonItem)
{
    self.navigationController?.popToViewController(ServiziVC(), animated: true)
}
```

Alternatively, you could override the `UINavigationController`'s delegate method as described here : [UINavigationController and back button action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256051/uinavigationcontroller-and-back-button-action)